Impact of Symmetry Preservation on Accurate Elastic Constant(Modulus) Calculations in Cubic Lattice Systems with Aliovalent Doping
I am currently working on calculating the bulk modulus of a 3D bulk structure with a cubic crystal system using VASP. The structure contains alkali ions, and my goal is to evaluate how the bulk modulus changes with aliovalent doping at various concentrations.
To maintain charge neutrality, I adjust the number of alkali ions in the structure. However, during this process, the lattice symmetry is broken, leading to optimized structures with lower symmetry such as tetragonal, monoclinic, or even trigonal crystal systems instead of the original cubic system.
Question:
Is it acceptable to calculate elastic constants based on structures with changed crystal systems, or should I aim to preserve the original cubic symmetry?
Current Setup:
I currently use ISIF = 3 to optimize both the lattice and atomic positions. My INCAR settings are as follows:
ALGO = Normal

EDIFF = 1E-6

EDIFFG = -0.02

ENCUT = 520

GGA = PS

IBRION = 2

ICHARG = 2

ISIF = 3

ISMEAR = 0

ISTART = 0

KPAR = 2

LCHARG = .FALSE.

LREAL = Auto

LWAVE = .FALSE.

NCORE = 8

NELM = 100

NELMDL = -8

NELMIN = 6

NSW = 300

PREC = Accurate

SIGMA = 0.05

This setup removes external pressure from the optimized structure. However, it often results in a reduced symmetry, deviating from the original cubic crystal system.
Potential Alternatives:
To address the symmetry issue, I am considering the following approaches:

ISIF = 7 followed by ISIF = 2:

Perform volume optimization with ISIF = 7, then refine atomic positions using ISIF = 2.

AIMD with NpT Ensemble:

Use the structure optimized with ISIF = 7 and ISIF = 2 as the starting point. Then, employ AIMD simulations under an NpT ensemble with constraints on lattice angles and lengths using an ICONST file.

Continue with ISIF = 3:

Allow the crystal system to change during optimization and calculate the elastic constants for the resulting structure.
I would greatly appreciate any advice or insights based on similar experiences.
Thank you!
